# Error importing a WSDL in SoapUI

Tags: wsdl, soapui

I'm getting this message when attempting to create a new SoapUI project and import a WSDL for Web Service Simulation. The error message seems incomplete as it does not actually say what tag is not being closed.

> Error loading [file:\C:\chad.wsdl]: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error:   does not close tag

Here's the WSDL:

```
    <wsdl:definitions name="Chad" targetNamespace="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/Chad.wsdl" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/Chad.wsdl" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

       <wsdl:message name="SayHiRequest">
          <wsdl:part name="text" type="xsd:string"/>
       </wsdl:message>
       <wsdl:message name="SayHiResponse">
          <wsdl:part name="text" type="xsd:string"/>
       </wsdl:message>

       <wsdl:portType name="Hello_PortType">
          <wsdl:operation name="sayHi">
             <wsdl:input message="tns:SayHiRequest"/>
             <wsdl:output message="tns:SayHiResponse"/>
          </wsdl:operation>
       </wsdl:portType>

       <wsdl:binding name="Hello_Binding" type="tns:Hello_PortType">
           <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
           <wsdl:operation name="sayHi">
              <soap:operation soapAction="sayHi"/>
              <wsdl:input>
                 <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:examples:chadservice" use="encoded"/>
              </wsdl:input>
              <wsdl:output>
                 <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:examples:chadservice" use="encoded"/>
              </wsdl:output>
           </wsdl:operation>
       </wsdl:binding>

       <wsdl:service name="Hello_Service">
          <wsdl:documentation>WSDL File for HelloService</documentation>
          <wsdl:port binding="tns:Hello_Binding" name="Hello_Port">
             <soap:address location="http://www.examples.com/chad/"/>
          </wsdl:port>
       </wsdl:service>
    </wsdl:definitions>
```

My WSDL seems to validate.

I've found some similar issues online where the wsdl is imported from an http url and the import results in this same error, but i'm importing straight from my C drive (not over http) so the suggested solutions have not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a namespace issue in the following line

Original line

```
<wsdl:documentation>WSDL File for HelloService</documentation>
```

Changed to

```
<wsdl:documentation>WSDL File for HelloService</wsdl:documentation>
```

Here is the updated wsdl

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="Chad" targetNamespace="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/Chad.wsdl" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/Chad.wsdl" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <wsdl:message name="SayHiRequest">
          <wsdl:part name="text" type="xsd:string"/>
       </wsdl:message>
       <wsdl:message name="SayHiResponse">
          <wsdl:part name="text" type="xsd:string"/>
       </wsdl:message>

       <wsdl:portType name="Hello_PortType">
          <wsdl:operation name="sayHi">
             <wsdl:input message="tns:SayHiRequest"/>
             <wsdl:output message="tns:SayHiResponse"/>
          </wsdl:operation>
       </wsdl:portType>

       <wsdl:binding name="Hello_Binding" type="tns:Hello_PortType">
           <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
           <wsdl:operation name="sayHi">
              <soap:operation soapAction="sayHi"/>
              <wsdl:input>
                 <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:examples:chadservice" use="encoded"/>
              </wsdl:input>
              <wsdl:output>
                 <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="urn:examples:chadservice" use="encoded"/>
              </wsdl:output>
           </wsdl:operation>
       </wsdl:binding>

       <wsdl:service name="Hello_Service">
          <wsdl:documentation>WSDL File for HelloService</wsdl:documentation>
          <wsdl:port binding="tns:Hello_Binding" name="Hello_Port">
             <soap:address location="http://www.examples.com/chad/"/>
          </wsdl:port>
       </wsdl:service>
    </wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Used the online validation tool [http://www.xmlvalidation.com](http://www.xmlvalidation.com) which immediately pointed to the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to load the WSDL in soapUI 4.5.2 without getting the error you got. Although, I did get the below error.

```
Tue Aug 20 11:30:21 ADT 2013:ERROR:Could not find element [{https://something.com/service/types}IsAvailableRequest] specified in part [parameters]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but a different cause:

```
Instead of:
https://sitename.com/prefix/app/services.asxm 

Use:   
https://sitename.com/prefix/app/services.asxm?WSDL
```

I hadn't used SOAP before and it wasn't immediately obvious that I was missing the ?WSDL from the url. Posting just in case anyone else has the same issue.